# EF Core filter data by date

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Hi everyone I just want to make a query with Where condition. My default query is.

```
var list = _Service.GetData(Id);
```

It returns object list and count is 110.

The sample data from Date property I want to compare is

```
StartDate:{4.09.2020 13:00:00}
```

The compare param is like

```
model.Start={30.11.2020 00:00:00}
```

My where query is

```
var list2 = _Service.GetData(Id).Where(x => x.StartDate>= model.Start);
```

This query returns null. Theese two are DateTime object. Where do I make mistake

My try is get date data from beginning date  `model.start`

**NEW**

Some more sample data comes from this query

I'm just gonna post dates not other attr.

```
Datetime StartDate
StartDate    {30.09.2020 14:00:00}
StartDate    {11.10.2020 13:00:00}
StartDate    {24.11.2020 00:03:00}
StartDate    {24.11.2020 15:01:00}
...
```

and more comes from GetData function without filter.

```
_Service calls context

  var list = _Service.GetData(Id);
```

The other parameter i just want to filter by date is.

```
    DateTime model.Start can be this values

model.Start    {20.11.2020 00:00:00}
model.Start    {12.10.2020 00:00:00}
model.Start    {25.09.2020 00:00:00}
```

... it's dynamic filter
Also my other try's which returns null to list

```
    var list2 = _Service.GetData(Id).Where(x => x.StartDate>= model.Start);
    var list3 = _Service.GetData(Id).Where(x => model.Start.Date >= x.StartDate.Date);
    var list4 = _Service.GetData(Id).Where(x => model.Start.Month >= x.StartDate.Month);
    var list5 = _Service.GetData(Id).Where(x => x.StartDate.Month >= model.Start.Month);
    var list6 = _Service.GetData(Id).Where(x => x.StartDate < DateTime.Now);
```

I just want to filter data with `model.Start` to `StartDate`

Comment: And you have verified that there are dates later than 30th of November in the data? The example you give is from September.

Comment: The first query gets all the data. What I want is get the date starts form model.Start date.Also yes there are a few later than 30th of november

Comment: You are asking for EF Core, but do not show any EF Core code. What is `GetData(Id)`? What does it return? If *"It returns object list"*, then further LINQ operators are performed in memory, hence has nothing to do with EF Core. What you need is (1) make sure `x.StartDate`  type is `DateTime` and **is stored** as datetime in database (2) You are executing EF Core query, e.g. `dbContext.Data.Where(...)` etc.

Comment: `Where()` does not return `null`. Do you mean to say that it returns an empty collection? Details like this matter when you're explaining the problem.

Comment: _service calls context in other layer.         public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
 is the entity and the data returns from GetData(Id) returns oıbject array which includes         DateTime StartDate . This property to I want to filter by

Comment: Also, the one data example you give (September 19th) wouldn't be included in the result since your looking for entries after (i.e. bigger than) November 30th.

Comment: I mean no offense because I want to solve your problem, but your explanations are hard to understand. It may be a translation issue. So, to get to the heart of the actual problem, please add this to your question (you've already provided some of this) (1) A few example entries (2) The date you want to filter against (3) The filter logic you use to apply that filter to the entries (4) The output you expect to see. Ideally, the output in (4) should be a subset of the data in (1), so that _some but not all_ entries were returned.

Comment: Should i need add more detail